# How to use --spec flag in env when using cypress

Tags: docker, cypress

I can start my cypress tests using:

```
docker run -it --env-file=.env -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e/cypress cypress/included:9.6.0 --spec cypress/integration/test/**/*-spec.js
```

Where `--spec` is variable which test should be runned.

Is there any way how to use `--spec` in my `.env` file? I didnt find any list of cypress env commands.

Comment: You mean you want to set `--spec` from an environment variable? The convention is for `--env-var` to become `CYPRESS_ENV_VAR`, per e.g. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use --spec like env variable. Variable `CYPRESS_ENV_SPEC` or `CYPRESS_SPEC` doesn't work.